# Invisible prop for html element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to add "invisible" property to HTML element?

By invisible I mean that it doesn't show up in DOM/inspector but parent component can read it.

For example:

```js
<Layout>
  <div left="true">...</div>
  <div left="right">...</div>
</Layout>
```

```js
// and in Layout component
Children.forEach(props.children, (child) => {
  if (child.props.left) {
    left = child;
  } else if (child.props.right) {
    right = child;
  }
});
```

I just don't like `left="true"` on div, it's my personal preference but I don't think it makes my question invalid. I also do not want to turn div into new component, any other ideas?

**Edit:**
This is not possible because React props are read only.

```js
child.props.left = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

You have a couple of options:

1. Really do what you've described
2. Use a `WeakMap` keyed by DOM elements, which is often a better choice

Neither of those shows up in the DOM inspector, which only shows you DOM information. #1 *would* show up if someone looked at all the properties of the element in devtools (but #2 wouldn't).

### Doing what you described

Although it's often considered poor practice, yes, you can add arbitrary properties to HTML elements by simply assigning to a property on the element. Pick your name carefully to avoid conflicts both with the DOM itself (now and in the future) and with other code that might also be doing this. Example:

```
// Setting it:
someDOMElement.__my_special_info = 42;
// ...
// Getting it:
console.log(someDOMElement.__my_special_info); // 42
```

### Use a `WeakMap`

Alternatively, you can use a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) where the keys are DOM elements and the values are the values you want:

```
// Create the map once:
const specialInfo = new WeakMap();
// ...
// Setting it:
specialInfo.set(someDOMElement, = 42);
// ...
// Getting it:
console.log(specialInfo.get(someDOMElement)); // 42
```

Since it's a `WeakMap`, it doesn't keep the element in memory if the element is removed from the DOM and nothing else refers to it (whereas a `Map` would, so it would be a bad idea to do this with a `Map`).

This has a couple of advantages:

1. You don't have any possibility of name conflicts
2. Other code can't see your information for the DOM element, because you can make the `WeakMap` entirely private to your code